# Changing the layout of an open source application

Tags: java, android

So I have a project for school, and they have not taught us android studio in the least and I have little experience with Javascript. I have looked at countless YouTube tutorials trying to figure my way out.

The project requires me to develop an android application that communicates with an ELM327 adapter. I am allowed to use open source software. I would like to take this: https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader

and improve the layout as well as add some additional features such as live graph plotting and live gauges.

The first thing I'd like to do is change the layout to a tabbed layout rather than the layout the app currently has. Can anyone assist me in the best possible way to begin doing this? I am reading as much as I can but seem to be making no progress.

Comment: clone or download the project and modify it as you see fit

Comment: Hint, given that the project has been discontinued by the owner, you should look at the forks to see who has been recently active / maintained so that the version is at least buildable: https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader/network

Comment: I have downloaded the project but as I try changing the layout, I'm getting a lot of different errors and I'm not sure where or how to start fixing it. 

I will look into the latest version, I didn't know about that. Thank you @MorrisonChang